# isset within an echo? Or is there a better way?

Tags: php, sql, echo, isset

```
$sql = "SELECT * from post where forum_id = $_GET[id]";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die('Error querying database.');     
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '' . $row['fourm_id']; 
        echo '<div id="post3">
            <p class="1">
            <span class="name">'.'
            ' .$row['name']. '</span>'.
            '<span class="trip">
            ' .' !'
            . $row['title'].''.
            ' </span>'.
            ' <span class="time">
            ' .$row['time']. '' . 
            ' </span>'.
            ' </p>
            <p class="2">
            <span class="texts">
            ' .$row['texts']. '' .
            ' </span>'.
            ' </p>'.
            if (!isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) { 
            }
             else {
             '<a href="delete_post.php?fourm_id=' . $row['id']. '>Delete</a>' . }
            ' </div>';
         } 
        mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

The mistake in the code is obvious, just showing what I am trying to do.

This echo I have here displays the users post, how would I go about sticking an isset in there so only admins can see the delete link? Or is there another way of doing it outside the echo with out it going outside the user post?

Comment: *sigh*, http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?
$data = array();
$sql  = "SELECT * from post where forum_id = ".intval($_GET['id']);
$res  = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($conn));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $data[] = $row;
}
?>
<?php foreach($data as $row): ?>
<?=$row['fourm_id']?>
<div id="post3">
  <p class="1">
    <span class="name"><?=$row['name']?></span>
    <span class="trip"> !<?=$row['title']?></span>
    <span class="time"><?=$row['time']?></span>
  </p>
  <p class="2">
    <span class="texts"><?=$row['texts']?></span>
  </p>
<?     if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"])): ?>
  <a href="delete_post.php?fourm_id=<?=$row['id']?>">Delete</a>
<?     endif ?>
</div>
<? endforeach ?>
```

Comment: You have made it so beautiful! Some of this is foreign to me but I'll give it a go before I copy and post! thanks!.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do it inline, you can either use the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) or something like `sprintf`.

Ternary operator (best if you only have a couple of insertions):

```
echo "Foo ".(isset($bar) ? "bar" : "");
```

`(s)printf` (best if you have several insertions):

```
printf("Foo %s", isset($bar) ? "bar" : "");
```

However this does not scale very much, so when you have large-scale "string construction" it's much saner to split the output into more than one statements:

```
echo "Foo ";
if (isset($bar)) {
    echo "bar";
}
```

This is best if you have lots of insertions.

Comment: So combining that with this if (!isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) { 
    }
     else {
     '<a href="delete_post.php?fourm_id=' . $row['id']. '>Delete</a>' . } how would it look?

Comment: @GarrettRobertson: `if(isset(...)) echo '<a href="delete...">';`. I have inverted the condition because you don't care about the "not set" branch.

Comment: Okay, I gotta' figure it out... based on my efforts here how would you do it? http://pastebin.com/G596nDJM

Comment: can't, that's the problem. Give me a minuet I'll try again.